# Suspend several functions invocations and use the returned value of first invoked in the rest of them?

Tags: android, concurrency, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines

Context: I have an app that sends the same request several times depending on user interaction.

I need to reduce as much as possible the IO operations, so my idea is to somehow enqueue the requests until the first one resolves. Then use the fetched data on the enqueued requests.

I think that one way to accomplish this would be using Java concurrency APIs (BlockingQueue, to name one).

I'm already using Coroutines and suspend functions and would be great use them for this, but sadly my current knowledge on those subjects is not enough yet.

Sample:

```
suspend fun getDataAndCalculate(): Int {
    val data = remote.getDataFromServer()
    return calculate(data)
}
```

Function `getDataAndCalculate()` can be invoked multiple times and from multiple threads, it would be great to somehow enqueue or suspend all these invocations while `remote.getDataFromServer()` is in execution. When `remote.getDataFromServer()` returns use `data` in all pending `getDataAndCalculate()` invocations.

¿Any idea or recommendation, please? ¿Is this recommended? ¿Do you know any design pattern to tackle this kind of problem?

Thanks!

(Not quite sure about the title, hope it describes what I want to accomplish, otherwise, I can improve it.)

Answer (score 0):

One possible & simple solution I can think of:

1. Create an in-memory cache, simple save the returned value at your repository level. You can add a timestamp too, and verify at your suspend function level if you consider the response outdated.
2. Add a state which represents if a request is already running (a simple flag, like `var isRunning: Boolean`, and if it's already running just suspend until you have a cached value.

It might not be the best approach though, other simple solutions:

1. If you're familiar with Channels or Flows, you could write some debouncing logic probably
2. At your ViewModel level, check if the previous request finished or not. The same `isRunning` functionality, with the constraint that requests need to be launched from the same vm.

These can do the job, but it might not be the most elegant solutions